# Reliable cross-reference to a frame in beamer

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I make extensive use of `beamer`'s overlay mechanism to build animations. Depending on the audience, but especially for the `handout` version, I then use `frame`-level overlay specifications to select the steps of the animation (i.e., slides of the frame) to be actually shown:

```
\begin{frame}<handout:2,4>[label=otherframe]{Other Frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<all:+->]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item -- this step also to be shown in handout mode
    \item Third Item
    \item Forth Item  -- this step also to be shown in handout mode
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

This causes an issue when cross-referencing to such a frame with `\ref{otherframe}`. If the `label=otherframe` option is passed, beamer generates a label for each slide of the frame (`otherframe<1>`, `otherframe<2>`, ...) and additionally the label `otherframe` as an alias to `otherframe<1>`. However, depending on the `frame`-level overlay specification, slide 1 might not be part of the deck, so the reference could not be resolved.

Of course, I could write `\ref{otherframe<2>}` in `handout` mode instead, but this would be bad separation of concerns. Given the multiple modes (`beamer`, `handout`), reference management would become a nightmare. The decision which steps of the animation to show should remain independent from how to refer to it as a whole.

**I consider this as a bug in beamer:** IMHO, `otherframe` should refer to the first *actually available* slide of the frame – which not always is `otherframe<1>`.

I am looking for suggestions and workarounds.

Complete MWE:

```
% \documentclass[beamer]{beamer}
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<handout:2,4>[label=otherframe]{Other Frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<all:+->]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item -- this step also to be shown in handout mode
    \item Third Item
    \item Forth Item  -- this step also to be shown in handout mode
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame, link to Other Frame}
  We have seen this on \ref{otherframe}! % not resolved in handout mode
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you place the label inside the frame `\begin{frame}<handout:2,4>{Other Frame}\label{otherframe}` it should always link to the first visible slide of your current mode. Disadvantages: This will cause "label already defined warnings" (but it should still work, because the first label is used) and you probably loose some functionality, e.g. `\againframe` does not work.

Comment: @samcarter: Thanks, that is an easy to apply workaround (I always believed that with multiple definition warnings the _last_ would win.) Would you mind turning your comment into an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disclaimer: the following workaround is no solution and has a couple of disadvantages

If you bypass beamer owns frame-label mechanism and use `\label{...}` inside the frame, you'll get working links for your example.

Warnings:

- You won't be able to use beamer features like `\againframe` with this approach
- It will produce warnings about multiple defined labels, but because you want to use the first occurrence, this should be no problem in your specific case.

---

```
% \documentclass[beamer]{beamer}
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<handout:2,4>{Other Frame}
    \label{otherframe}
  \begin{itemize}[<all:+->]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item -- this step also to be shown in handout mode
    \item Third Item
    \item Forth Item  -- this step also to be shown in handout mode
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame, link to Other Frame}
  We have seen this on \ref{otherframe}! % not resolved in handout mode
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the warnings read a bit over-cautiously, as one can use `\label` and beamer‘s `label=` option for the same frame (with different identifiers, of course). So in the end it is a couple of warnings and two labels for the frame, which is not ideal, but well-workable without unbearable side effects.